# PowerShell script not zipping on different computer

Tags: powershell, scripting, zip, 7zip, maxlength

I have the following script for zipping old files:

```
# Zipping old files and sending them to a file on desktop if older than 60 days

Function Zip {    
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$zipFile
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String[]]$toBeZipped
  )
  $null = & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" A -tzip $zipFile $toBeZipped
}

$Days = 60    
$LastWrite = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-$Days)
$TargetFolder = "D:\Testing\*"

$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname

Zip "$($ENV:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\TEST.zip" $Files
```

I worked when I tested it on a VM and one physical machine. 
However, when I tried it on a different computer, it failed. 
This is what I got:

```
Program '7z.exe' failed to run: The filename or extension is too long
At C:\Users\Admin\Documents\zip help.ps1:23 char:9
+ $null = & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" A -tzip $zipFile $toBeZippe ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At C:\Users\Admin\Documents\zip help.ps1:23 char:1
+ $null = & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" A -tzip $zipFile $toBeZippe ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

The script can't use 7-zip. The other computers had 7-Zip in the exact same file path so I am unsure of what my problem is. Any input will be appreciated.

Edit: I can confirm the error is because of the long file path. Tried my script on a file with shorter path and it worked just fine.

Comment: have you _confirmed_ that the exe is in the expected location on the erroring system?

Comment: Yep, same place as other systems

Comment: then you need to add some output that shows what the $Vars in the call contain. it _may_ be referring to the content of one of those `$zipFile $toBeZippe` variables.

Comment: Ok. I'm a noob at this. Can I get an example of what that would look like?

Comment: comment out the line that starts with `$null = & "C:\` and then add a line just after the `$null = & "C:\` line for each $Var that is in that command. that will output the values in those lines at that time.

Comment: I can almost guarantee that the full file path of one of the files in `$files` is too long, and 7 zip can't archive it due to the file path length. Don't blame them, blame Windows. On the failing computer run `$files | Measure-Object Length -Max` and take a look at the length of the longest path, and let us know what it is.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: The puzzling thing is that if you provoke the path-too-long error manually, you get a different error message (a warning from `7z` itself, "The parameter is incorrect"): `7z a t ('x' * 256)`. Similarly, if you exceed the max. command-line length, you get "The command line is too long": `7z a t ('x' * 8192)`. The actual error message suggests that PowerShell was fundamentally unable to invoke `7z.exe`; the mystery is what path the error message relates to, as it can't be `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"`. Alexis, is there _remoting_ involved? How are you invoking your script?

Comment: No remoting, I just use ISE to invoke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out what was causing this. The folder contained a lot of other folders inside of it. The `-Recurse` made the script look in every folder, causing this problem. All I had to do was adjust the script to remove the `-Recurse` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `-Depth` after `-Recurse` to limit the depth

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.4#example-8-get-items-using-the-depth-parameter)